# ESLint Espected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression on void function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb, typescript-eslint

### Issue Description:

I've begun working on a project with [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) and [eslint](/questions/tagged/eslint). Issue is, eslint gives me an unexpected error on what seems to be a properly declared function

---

### Code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

type Props = {
  options: Array<string>
};

const Switch: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  const [choice, setChoice] = useState<number>(0);

  // eslint gives error @ following function
  const handleSwitchChange = ():void => {
    choice + 1 >= options.length ? setChoice(0) : setChoice(choice + 1)
  };

  return (
    <div>{options[choice]}</div>
    <button onClick={handleSwitchChange}>Change choice</button>
  );
};
```

---

### Further details:

Now this works as expected, but despite the fact the function I'm passing to is of declared type `void` eslint gives me the following error:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

Now I don't want to just disable the rule, but I don't see anything inherently wrong with the code. Is there any way to write the function properly so es-lint doesn't complain?

---

### ESLint error *(extra info)*

The specific eslint module which raises the error

```
 {
    "resource": "<PATH CENSORED>/src/components/forms/Switch.tsx",
    "owner": "eslint",
    "code": "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.",
    "source": "eslint",
    "startLineNumber": 12,
    "startColumn": 5,
    "endLineNumber": 12,
    "endColumn": 85
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have an arrow function with curly braces, its body must include at least one *statement* (as the error message suggests, an assignment or function call, or an `if` or `return` statement or something similar):

```js
const handleSwitchChange = {
  // Statements must go here
};
```

You've actually given an *expression* that (type checking aside) could appear on the right-hand side of an assignment or a function parameter:

```js
// Syntactically valid, not necessarily meaningful
const hypothetical = choice + 1 >= options.length ? setChoice(0) : setChoice(choice + 1);
someFunction(choice + 1 >= options.length ? setChoice(0) : setChoice(choice + 1));
```

You have a couple of options.  Easiest is to change the arrow function to a form that takes an expression by removing the curly braces

```js
const handleSwitchChange = (): void =>
  choice + 1 >= options.length ? setChoice(0) : setChoice(choice + 1);
```

There are various ways to refactor this to look more like a statement, like replacing the ternary operator with an `if` statement, or by moving the function up to the top level.

```js
// Equally valid with or without curly braces
// (Curly braces explicitly ignore the return value)
const handleSwitchChange = (): void => {
  setChoice(choice + 1 >= options.length ? 0 : choice + 1);
};
```